# Reading files in subdirectory in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I am trying to read files in sub directories.

```
"use strict";
const PORT = 8080;
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
function serverFile(path, res){
    //async method
    fs.readFile(path, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
             console.error(err);
             res.statusCode = 500;
             res.end("Server error: Could not read file");
             return;
        }
        //at this point, there is no error
        res.end(data);
    });
}
function serveDirectory(newPath, res){
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, files){
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.end("Server Error: ");
        }
        var html = "<p> Index of " + path + "</p>";
        html += "<ul>";
        html += files.map(function(item){
            return "<li><a href='"+path.join(newPath, item) +"'>" + item + "</a></li>";
        }).join("");
        html += "</ul>";
        res.end(html);
    });  
}
/**
 * @function handleRequest 
 * Request handler for our http server
 * @param {http.ClientRequest} req - the http requeset object
 * @param {http.ServerResponse} res - the http response object
 */
function handleRequest(req, res){
    /*console.log(req.url);
    var path = "public" + req.url;*/
    var temp = url.parse(req.url, true).pathname;
    var aPath = 'public'+temp;
    fs.stat(aPath, (err, stats) =>{
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.end("fs.stat error");
            return;
        }
        if(stats.isDirectory()){
            serveDirectory('public'+req.url+'/', res);
        }
        if(stats.isFile()){
            serverFile(aPath, res);

        }
    })
} 
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port "+PORT);
});
```

Once I am in subdirectory, I can see a list of my files. However, their address is itself, not `subdirectory/file`. I know it is caused by my `serveDirectory` function(`<a href='"+item +"'>" + item + "</a></li>`). I want to handle this issue in my `handleRequest` function, since this function can classify file and directory, but no luck. Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply prepend the directory to the path:

```
    html += files.map(function(item){
        return "<li><a href='"+path.join(path, item) +"'>" 
         + item + 
        "</a></li>";
    }).join("");
```

You will need to call `const path = require("path")` at the start of your module - but you'd need to do that sooner or later anyway.

Comment: Did you put `const path = require("path")` at the beginning of the file? If you did, what is your node.js version?

Comment: mine is v9.4.0. I added `const path = require("path")` and use this `path`. it has join function, but `path.join(newPath, item)` does not work well.